# Shift distplot up

Tags: python, seaborn

I have a distribution plot created with seaborn, I'd like to shift it up so I could plot multiples in the same plot at different heights. It is important that they are not overlapping and are instead at different heights in the same plot.

The code I have is:

```
sns.distplot(x, color="red", hist=False)
l1 = ax.lines[0]
x1 = l1.get_xydata()[:,0]
y1 = l1.get_xydata()[:,1]
ax.fill_between(x1,y1, color="red")
```

Is there a way to shift it up? So that for example, the zero line is at y=1 instead of y=0? Couldn't find a way to do it, maybe there is another way to do it that doesn't involve `distplot` but I just dont know it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like so?

```
dists = [np.random.normal(loc=i, size=(1000,)) for i in range(5)]

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)
for d,y0 in zip(dists,np.arange(5)*0.1+0.1):
    sns.distplot(d, hist=False, ax=ax1)
    sns.distplot(d, hist=False, ax=ax2)
    l = ax2.lines[-1]
    l.set_ydata(l.get_ydata()+y0)
ax1.set_ylim(0,1)
ax2.set_ylim(0,1)
```

[image]